# Installing nsfw via NPM fails with missing node_api.h

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have an Angular 10/Electron 10 project, and try to install [nsfw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nsfw) (node-sentinel-file-watcher).

During installation I receive this error below:

```
$ npm i nsfw
[...]
[...]
> node-gyp rebuild
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nsfw/src/NSFW.o
In file included from ../src/NSFW.cpp:1:
In file included from ../src/../includes/NSFW.h:7:
/Users/foo/Desktop/bar/node_modules/node-addon-api/napi.h:4:10: fatal error: 'node_api.h' file not found
#include <node_api.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/nsfw/src/NSFW.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
```

I could find the file here:

```
/usr/local/include/node/node_api.h
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/foo/.electron-gyp/9.0.4/include/node/node_api.h
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/foo/.electron-gyp/9.1.0/include/node/node_api.h
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/foo/.electron-gyp/9.1.1/include/node/node_api.h
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/foo/.electron-gyp/10.0.0-beta.14/include/node/node_api.h
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/foo/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.5.0/include/node/node_api.h
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/foo/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.18.2/include/node/node_api.h
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/foo/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.1.0/include/node/node_api.h
```

Can anyone help me and point out what I might miss here?